# Matlab - Save upon Key Press

Tags: matlab

So, here's what I want to do.  Basically, when a certain key is pressed, I want to initalize a save function (thinking of uisave to save all parameters in a .mat file) and quit my script.  How would I do this?  I messed around with waitforkeypress, but that halts all progress; I want to script to continue to run until this event occurs.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You should show us some of the code you have written and we can help you from there.

Answer (score 3):

Use the `'WindowKeyPressFcn'` property of your figure. You can set it to point to a function of yours (where you can do the saving):

```
f = gcf; %// get a handle to your window
set(gcf,'WindowKeyPressFcn',@myFun)
```

Or you can directly insert a string, which will get executed:

```
set(gcf,'WindowKeyPressFcn','disp(''Hello there! Have you pressed a key?'')')
```

You might want to use the `'WindowKeyReleaseFcn'` property too.

Comment: Thanks for the response, but I'm not sure how to actually use the '@myfun portion.  Suppose that, when a key is pressed, I want to change a variable which will allow me to halt progress ina  for loop.  How would I do this?  WOuld I change @myfun to 'var = 1' for example?

Comment: @Incognito I'm not sure you can alter a workspace variable from a figure. Maybe try declaring that variable as `global`